# Jackson: Returning just part of the response

Tags: java, json, jackson

Currently service response looks like this:

```
{
    "values": [
        {
            "field1": "value",
            .................

        },
        {
            "field1": "value",
            .................

        }
   ]
   metadata1:[],
   metadata2:"-"
}
```

But just want to send array of values as response. Like this

```
[
 {
   "field1": "value",
    .................   
 },
 {
   "field1": "value",
   ................
 }
]
```

I am able to suppress metadata info with the help of `@JsonIgnoreProperties`. But response still like this:

```
{
        "values": [
            {
                "field1": "value",
                .................

            },
            {
                "field1": "value",
                .................

            }
       ]
    }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have currently? (with the metadata surpressed) You've got a good object representation. The object would have a single field called values which would be a list of the objects represented in the JSON array. That's exactly the style of JSON you want to be working with.

Comment: Consumer is expecting a JSON array in return. This response returns a JSON Object. Actually this more of a backward compatibility issue so can not expect consumer to change their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to achieve using [the @JsonValue annotation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations) which can change the representation of the of your java class. Just add a method annotated with this annotation to your response class that returns the values collection. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonValue {
    public static class Bean {
        private final List<String> values;

        public Bean(List<String> values) {
            this.values = values;
        }

        @JsonValue
        public List<String> getValues() {
            return values;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Bean bean = new Bean(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(bean));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
["a","b","c"]
```